# Search results order varies each time in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr

We have 200k records. When running search query for the first time with size: 500 I am getting results in doc-1, doc-2, doc-3. But when I run the same search query for the second time I am getting the order changed to doc-2, doc-1, etc ... why the search result order varies each time when we run the same query ?

Query : {"explain":true,"size":500,"query":{"query_string":{"query":" ( (NAME:\"BANK AMERICA\")^50 OR (Names.Name:(BANK AMERICA))^30 OR (NAME_PAIR:\"BANK AMERICA\")^30 OR (NORMAL_NAME:(BANK AMERICA) AND CITY:\"\" ) ^40 OR (NORMAL_NAME:(BANK AMERICA))^30 OR (Styles.value:\"BS\")^5 OR (NORMAL_NAME:\"BANK AMERICA\")^5 OR (address.streetName:\"\" AND CITY:\"\")^30 OR (ZIP:\"\")^6 OR (address.streetName:\"\")^6 OR (address.streetNumber:\"\" AND address.streetName:\"\")^15 OR (telephones.telephone:\"\")^50 OR (mailAddresses.postbox:\"\")^6 ) "}},"sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}},{"statusIndicator":{"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{"NAME":{"filter":{"term":{"NAME":"ATLS"}}}}}

when running the above the the results are :

"hits": {
    "total": 106421,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": 0,
        "_node": "1",
        "_index": "allocation_e1",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "217600050_826_E1",
        "_score": 2.9569159,
        "_routing": "E1",
        "_source": {
          "sample_number": 217600050,
          "countryCode": 101,
          "state": "E1",
          "name": "BANK of AMERICA Plc",

when ruining the same query oneagain the results are :

Query : {"explain":true,"size":500,"query":{"query_string":{"query":" ( (NAME:\"BANK AMERICA\")^50 OR (Names.Name:(BANK AMERICA))^30 OR (NAME_PAIR:\"BANK AMERICA\")^30 OR (NORMAL_NAME:(BANK AMERICA) AND CITY:\"\" ) ^40 OR (NORMAL_NAME:(BANK AMERICA))^30 OR (Styles.value:\"BS\")^5 OR (NORMAL_NAME:\"BANK AMERICA\")^5 OR (address.streetName:\"\" AND CITY:\"\")^30 OR (ZIP:\"\")^6 OR (address.streetName:\"\")^6 OR (address.streetNumber:\"\" AND address.streetName:\"\")^15 OR (telephones.telephone:\"\")^50 OR (mailAddresses.postbox:\"\")^6 ) "}},"sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}},{"statusIndicator":{"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{"NAME":{"filter":{"term":{"NAME":"ATLS"}}}}}

hits": {
    "total": 106421,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_shard": 0,
        "_node": "1",
        "_index": "allocation_e1",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "239958846_826_E1",
        "_score": 2.9571724,
        "_routing": "E1",
        "_source": {
          "sample_number": 239958846,
          "countryCode": 101,
          "state": "E1",
          "name": "BANK of AMERICA Plc",

when running the same query the document order gets differs why do the document order changes when running the same query ?

please help on this thanks in advance

Comment: You should add the query and a corresponding response sample to your post so that SO users can help you.

Comment: A few more questions: #1 Do you ever get the same result set? Does the data get changed? Is the data possibly reindexed between searches? Also, is there any way for you to push the actual query string that hits Solr into a log? The code looks like there is a lot of things substituted on the fly,  so it would be nice to see what those actual things are when the query is executed. (Does that make sense? Or did I miss something?)

Comment: Every time we are getting the different result set for the same query.If i run the same query multiple times only 2 records are getting interchanged between first and second. No re-indexing happens between search. Do you have any idea we are using elastic search and not solr. Though its a common issue we would expect help from solr too ...

Answer (score 0):

Run your queries in say descending order, based on UID, and you will get the same results.

Compare the following examples.

Unsorted:

[image]

Sorted ascending:
[image]

Comment: Solr takes `score desc` as default sort parameter.

Comment: Hi @ericLavault, are you saying my argument is wrong or that the docs are supposed to be returned in the same order for the same query?

Comment: Hi, I think the statement "Solr does not guarantee to return the results in any particular order" is false, Solr returns results according to the specified sort param if any and falls back with `score desc` if not set, so there is always a sort order. Also, if the OP really runs the _same_ search query, the sort param, specified or not, should end up being the same.

Comment: @ericLavault, Thanks for pointing it out - just found it: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-ThesortParameter Thanks again.

user3351014, Could you share two example queries that yield different results, together with the results, so we can figure out what is going on?

Comment: @ ericLavault @Lefty G Balogh edited my post and added the queries and response